# How to remove an item from a paper-listbox?

Tags: listbox, dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I can add an item to a `paper-listbox` with

```
Polymer.dom($['mylistbox']).append(paperItem);
```

However I'm having trouble deleting it from the list afterwards. I tried:

```
paperItem.remove();
```

That initially makes it dissapear, but it appears again after selecting another item in the list. How do I remove a `paper-item` from a listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Polymer.dom($['mylistbox']).removeChild(paperItem);
```