# How to Remove a Polymer paper-listbox Item in an AngularDart Component

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart, paper-elements

I generate a paper-listbox as follows:

```
  <paper-listbox  class="scroll-list gutter" id="index">
    <paper-item class="index-entry" *ngFor="let composition of compositions" [class.selected]="composition == selectedComposition" (click)="onSelect(composition)">
      {{ composition.name }}
    </paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
```

I have a method that deletes an item from the database. I want to remove the corresponding entry from the list as well. I found [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053131/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-paper-listbox) and tried it. It gave a no such method error when I ran it. Then I tried:

```
PaperListbox index;
...
index = querySelector('#index');
...
index.remove();
```

It removes the entire listbox. I was in the ball park so I tried:

```
index.selectedItem().remove();
```

That gave me the browser console error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Class 'PaperItem' has no instance method 'call'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'call'
Receiver: Instance of 'PaperItem'
Arguments: []
```

Given that the error mentions paper-item makes me think I'm getting close, but I'm out of ideas. How does one delete a paper-listbox item? For extra credit, how does one add an item? That's my next task.

Comment: Why don't you just remove it from `compositions`?

Comment: Because I spent most of my life coding assembler and keep forgetting some things are automatic. lol. Go ahead make it an answer and I'll approve it or I can just answer it myself.

Comment: That's quite a change :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the item from `composition` and `*ngFor` updates the list of `<paper-item ...>` entries automatically.